# Get Row count in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want Total rows of below SQL query.

```
SELECT ParameterName, MAX(param_Value), MIN(param_Value) 
FROM MONITORING_PARAMETER_VALUES 
GROUP BY ParameterName;
```

Result:-

```
   ParameterName | max(param_Value) |  min(param_Value)
   EDS           |               4  |                1
   Table's       |               10 |                5
```

So clearly number of row's are 2 And this is want to get using sql query.

Comment: @shA.t dont think that Count(DISTINCT ParameterName) wil help. let me edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

The row count that the query would return is given by this expression:

```
select count(distinct parametername) + max(parametername is null)
from MONITORING_PARAMETER_VALUES;
```

Note that the expression considers `NULL` values.

If you want the rows returned by your query, one method is to enumerate them using variables:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn, MAX(param_Value), MIN(param_Value) 
FROM MONITORING_PARAMETER_VALUES CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
GROUP BY ParameterName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Sum(cnt) as countCol
from
(
SELECT 1 as cnt
FROM MONITORING_PARAMETER_VALUES 
GROUP BY ParameterName
) as tab
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use @@rowcount after your query:

```
SELECT ParameterName, MAX(param_Value), MIN(param_Value) 
FROM MONITORING_PARAMETER_VALUES 
GROUP BY ParameterName

select @@rowcount
```

This will return the row count of the previusly executed select.